# How does The Moment's user interface work?

Tags: doctor-who

I don't understand why only the 8½th Doctor can see and hear The Moment. How does it work? It's not your basic hologrammatic user interface, because then a) it would be visible to everyone, and b) it would be limited to the near vicinity of the weapon itself, that is, in the shed on Gallifrey.

So, is The Moment sitting in the Doctor's mind or something? If so, are we sure that her words are actually what she says, or is the Doctor imagining her?

Comment: Also just to affirm he is not the 8.5 Doctor... he is in fact the True 9th Doctor.

Comment: True, true, but we only found that out this week. And that Ten was actually two doctors. (So if we have another multiple-Doctor episode, David Tennant can appear twice!)

Comment: all semantics, John Hurt was in my view fixed as the 9th doctor during the Day of the Doctor when the 3 doctors combined to save Gallifrey, as that was an action "in the name of the Doctor" it redeemed his status as a "true" doctor. Also, David Tennant's doctor had clearly used up two regenerations when he pulled that little trick with the regeneration energy, so it was refreshing to see a bit of consistency from the showrunners for once! p.s. good  question Mr Lister.

Answer (score 6):

Not explicitly answered. It is possible that *The Moment* is projecting a holographic image directly to The Warrior Doctor's visual cortex (sight related area of the brain). This has been mentioned in Who before. (The Doctor's holographic clothes in *Time of the Doctor* were only visible to Clara and not her family. Similarly River Song's .... *backup* (?) was also visible only to The Doctor and Clara, but not to Jenny, Strax or Madame Vastra.)

Since only The Warrior Doctor was present at the time of it's activation, the image was only for that version of The Doctor. Also, The Moment is sentient. Maybe she chose not to project herself to the other versions of The Doctor.

Comment: You might want to mention the parallels to Eleven's selective-vision hologrammatic clothing in *Time of the Doctor*, and to River Song's psychic ghost.

Comment: That was precisely what I was getting at. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, so you are saying the Moment projects her image and voice directly to the Doctor's visual and auditory cortexes, across all space and time? While that is a possibility, it would have been nice if that would have been mentioned. As it is now, it is not explained, and the Doctor seems ashamed of the fact that only he can see and hear her. I mean, as if he thinks he is imagining her.

Comment: Yes, it should have been mentioned, but such smaller intricacies are often left out in Who. The Doctor didn't seem _ashamed_ though. He did avoid mentioning her, but that was ofcourse because she herself asked him not to.